# refering to buildscript from Inner class in build.gradle

Tags: class, groovy, gradle, project, inner-classes

I have an inner class inside a buid.gradle:

```
class MyClass {
   MyClass(String path) {
       project.project(path);
   }
}
```

That is failing, because it cannot find project. Is there any workaround for this?

Comment: Pass project to it when you call the constructor?

Comment: Yeap, but I was trying to avoid that, there should be another way, since from a JVM perspective it is perfectly accessible.